# Google Maps Escaped Characters Not Displayed Correctly &#39 - XML and Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, xml, utf-8, apostrophe

Completely stumped here. Can't get &#39 (apostrophe) to display correctly... Used the tutorial from google [Google Maps Tutorial](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/mysql-to-maps) to create a map from my database.  It connects to my database, creates an XML file and then that XML file is referenced to create the map.

The following code is my PHP file that creates the XML. See the escape code.

```
<?php

// Escape Characters
function parseToXML($htmlStr)
{
$xmlStr=str_replace('<','&lt;',$htmlStr);
$xmlStr=str_replace('>','&gt;',$xmlStr);
$xmlStr=str_replace('"','&quot;',$xmlStr);
$xmlStr=str_replace("'",'&#39;',$xmlStr);
$xmlStr=str_replace("&",'&amp;',$xmlStr);
return $xmlStr;
}


$servername = "localhost";
$username = "XXX";
$password = "XXX";
$dbname = "XXX";



// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 


// Select all the rows in the markers table
$sql = "
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE status = 'ACTIVE'";


$result = $conn->query($sql);
if (!$result) {
  die('Invalid query: ' . mysqli_error());
}

header("Content-type: text/xml");

// Start XML file, echo parent node
echo "<?xml version='1.0' ?>";
echo '<markers>';
$ind=0;
// Iterate through the rows, printing XML nodes for each
while ($row = @mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
  // Add to XML document node
  echo '<marker ';
  echo 'fac_id="' . $row['fac_id'] . '" ';
  echo 'fac_name="' . parseToXML($row['fac_name']) . '" ';
  echo 'address="' . parseToXML($row['address']) . '" ';
  echo 'lat="' . $row['lat'] . '" ';
  echo 'lng="' . $row['lng'] . '" ';
  echo 'region="' . $row['region'] . '" ';
  echo '/>';
  $ind = $ind + 1;
}

// End XML file
echo '</markers>';

?>
```

Here is a line from the XML file that was created above. The apostrophe is represented as &#39

```
<marker fac_id="123" fac_name="St. Luke&#39;s MC" address="1800 East Van Buren Street" lat="33.451542" lng="-112.043129" region="West C"/>
```

Below is the html file (not working as I removed personal data) used to create the actual map. I really have no experience in javascript, so I am unsure why the apostrophe is not decoded?

Screenshot of improperly displayed apostrophe:
[Google Map Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NmuQn.jpg)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html >
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <title>Using MySQL and PHP with Google Maps</title>
    <style>
      /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>

    <script>
      var customLabel = {
        'East A': {
          label: 'A'
        },
        'West C': {
          label: 'C'
        },
        'North D': {
          label: 'D'
        },
 'East K': {
          label: 'K'
        },
 'North M': {
          label: 'M'
        },
 'South S': {
          label: 'S'
        }
      };

        function initMap() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(35.845424, -93.738202),
          zoom: 4.75
        });
        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

          // Change this depending on the name of your PHP or XML file
          downloadUrl('http://example.com/xmlmaker.php', function(data) {
            var xml = data.responseXML;
            var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('marker');
            Array.prototype.forEach.call(markers, function(markerElem) {
              var fac_id = markerElem.getAttribute('fac_id');
              var fac_name = markerElem.getAttribute('fac_name');
              var address = markerElem.getAttribute('address');
              var region = markerElem.getAttribute('region');
              var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
                  parseFloat(markerElem.getAttribute('lat')),
                  parseFloat(markerElem.getAttribute('lng')));

              var infowincontent = document.createElement('div');
              var strong = document.createElement('strong');
              strong.textContent = fac_name
              infowincontent.appendChild(strong);
              infowincontent.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));

              var text = document.createElement('text');
              text.textContent = address
              infowincontent.appendChild(text);
              var icon = customLabel[region] || {};
              var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: point,
                label: icon.label
              });
              marker.addListener('click', function() {
                infoWindow.setContent(infowincontent);
                infoWindow.open(map, marker);
              });
            });
          });
        }



      function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
        var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
            new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
            new XMLHttpRequest;

        request.onreadystatechange = function() {
          if (request.readyState == 4) {
            request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
            callback(request, request.status);
          }
        };

        request.open('GET', url, true);
        request.send(null);
      }

      function doNothing() {}
    </script>
    <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=ABC1234567890&callback=initMap">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why use `&#39;` instead of `&apos;`?

Answer (score 1):

Your `parseToXML($htmlStr)` function is nuking `&` substitutions from earlier replacements because after it substitutes, say, `'` for `&#39;`, it then proceeds to ruin `&#39;` by replacing `&` with `&amp;`.

All of those characters don't have to be replaced in all contexts.  See [**Simplified XML Escaping**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46637835/290085), and refine your `parseToXML()` function and where it's called accordingly.

Comment: Okay so I could just not escape ' and " and & and > ???

Could I also remove both instances of parseToXML?  Sorry not familiar in this area, but badly need to use google maps for this task.  Thanks a bunch!

Comment: You've not exactly summarized the rules correctly.  I cannot phrase them any simpler than I've done [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46637835/290085)

Comment: I saw your linked post, but I am still confused as to how I should alter my original code.  Can you provide an example of what you would change.  I don't want you to do the work for me, but I am unsure of how to proceed.  Thank you!

Comment: On the contrary, that's precisely what your comment indicates that you do want.  **I've answered your question but will not be doing your work for you.** Good luck.

Comment: I'm sorry.  Certainly not due to laziness, I'm just not experienced in the subject area. I think I understand that in most cases only < and & need to be escaped.  If I comment out (//) my other escape commands it corrects the issue, but not sure if this is proper?  Also if I remove both instances of parseToXML from my php file, it corrects the issue, but again I am not sure if I really should be doing this. I didn't write any of this code myself. It all came from the Google tutorial. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/mysql-to-maps

Comment: @Talsma: simply change `parseToXML($htmlStr)` to replace `'&'` first instead of last, then the rest of your replacements will work fine.